# This is about jquery 'append', i want know why and how to solve it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

first, there are codes I wrote.

```
<body>
    <a href="javascript:;" id="btn">add</a>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup">
        <a href="javascript:;" id="sure">sure</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel">cancel</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#btn').click(function(){
                $('.popup').show();
                $('#sure').on('click', function(){
                    var $box = "<div class='box'></div>";
                    $('.panel').append($box);
                });
                $('#cancel').on('click', function(){
                    $('.popup').hide();
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

then,there are steps i did.

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nRnN.png)

why i click the cancel button at first, and next time i click Sure button, there appears two DIVs actually.I just want one div.
 How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Do not add the `event-handler` as many times you click on `#btn`.

Bind `click` handlers for *"sure"* and *"cancel"* out of the click handler for *"#btn"*

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $('.popup').show();
  });
  $('#sure').on('click', function() {
    var $box = "<div class='box'>Added</div>";
    $('.panel').append($box);
  });
  $('#cancel').on('click', function() {
    $('.popup').hide();
  });
})
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" id="btn">add</a>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="popup">
  <a href="javascript:;" id="sure">sure</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel">cancel</a>
</div>
```

**If** elements in the `pop-up` are created dynamically, Use [**`Event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $('.popup').show();
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#sure', function() {
    var $box = "<div class='box'>Added</div>";
    $('.panel').append($box);
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#cancel', function() {
    $('.popup').hide();
  });
})
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:;" id="btn">add</a>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="popup">
  <a href="javascript:;" id="sure">sure</a>
  <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel">cancel</a>
</div>
```

Comment: but the popup is a form,there are some inputs i want fill with texts that display in the div. Is it same?

Comment: @lifeng1893 – Are elements in `form` created dynamically ? Or they exist in the DOM but in hidden state ?

Comment: i tried, but it not work yet, because there also a edit button in the popup, and i don't know how to describe it.thanks anyway.@Rayon